# How do I category based on a workflow status?

Tags: sql

I have a workflow table which I would like to group them into 2 categories based on the workflow status. Example as follow. I have 3 unique IDs, each unique ID has different workflow status. If a workflow of an unique Id contains "Missing Support Documentation", "Return to Owner for Correction", I would like to category the whole Unique ID as "Bad Application". Otherwise, category the Unique ID as "Good Application"

```
UniqueID   Status
==================
ABC123      Application Submitted
ABC123      Work in Progress
ABC123      Application Approved
ABC123      Application Activated
DEF567      Submission
DEF567      Work in Progress
DEF567      Missing Support Documentation
DEF567      Return to Owner for Correction
DEF567      Resubmitted
DEF567      Work in Progress
KFG678      Application Submitted
KFG678      Work in Progress
KFG678      Application Approved
KFG678      Application Activated
```

I would like to result to be:

```
UniqueID   Status                            Application_Category
=================================================================
ABC123      Application Submitted            Good application
ABC123      Work in Progress                 Good application
ABC123      Application Approved             Good application
ABC123      Application Activated            Good application
DEF567      Submission                       Bad application
DEF567      Work in Progress                 Bad application
DEF567      Missing Support Documentation    Bad application
DEF567      Return to Owner for Correction   Bad application
DEF567      Resubmitted                      Bad application
DEF567      Work in Progress                 Bad application
KFG678      Application Submitted            Good application
KFG678      Work in Progress                 Good application
KFG678      Application Approved             Good application
KFG678      Application Activated            Good application
```

Answer (score 0):

just use case when is ok

```
    select 
      UniqueID, status,
      case when status in ('Missing Support Documentation',
          'Return to Owner for Correction') then 'Bad application'
           else 'Good application' end as Application_Category
    from table
```

you can just use inert into with the query to create a new table to store the data.

ok, this is my bad i didn't get your require clearly, and now i done this and tested on Mysql and MS SQL and i think it will work for Oracle

```
    select UniqueID,status,'Bad application' as Application_Category from table a 
      where exists
       (select 1 from
            (select distinct UniqueID
               from table where status in ('Missing Support Documentation',
      'Return to Owner for Correction')) b 
                 where a.UniqueID = b.UniqueID)

    UNION ALL

    select UniqueID,status,'Good application' as Application_Category from table a 
      where not exists
         (select 1 from
            (select distinct UniqueID from table 
               where status in ('Missing Support Documentation',
      'Return to Owner for Correction')) b 
                 where a.UniqueID = b.UniqueID)
```

or you can use a temp table like this

```
      select distinct UniqueID into table1 from table 
               where status in ('Missing Support Documentation',
      'Return to Owner for Correction');

       select a.UniqueID,a.status,
              case when b.UniqueID is null then "Good application" 
                   else "Bad application" end as Application_Category
       from table a left join table1 b on a.UniqueID=b.UniqueID
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this. But it ends up only the row that has 'Missing Support Documentation' and 'Return to Owner for Correct' categorized as 'Bad application' The rest of the row of the same UniqueID are categorized as 'Good application'

Comment: already updated a new one. feel sorry for misunderstand your question before.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `IF` keyword will work. Then use the `IN` keyword to find if a column is in an array of multiple values.

You will then need to use the `AS` keyword because the previous column name was unbelievably long. We can use that keyword to rename it.

Here's how it looks in `mysql`.

```
SELECT UNIQUE_ID, STATUS, 
IF(STATUS IN ("Missing Support Documentation", "Return to owner for correction"), 
"Bad Application", "Good Application") AS application_grade
FROM table
```

I created an `sqlfiddle` here

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eff5b/6/0

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using a `CASE` expression like

```
select t1.UniqueID, t1.Status, 
case when t1.UniqueID = t2.UniqueID
then 'Bad Application' else 'Good Application' end as Application_Category
from mytable t1
left join ( select distinct UniqueID from mytable 
where Status in ( 'Missing Support Documentation', 'Return to Owner for Correction')) t2
on t1.UniqueID = t2.UniqueID
order by t1.UniqueID;
```

[See a Demo Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d807b4/4)

Comment: Thank you very much for your guidance. However, I kept getting an error

Comment: you shouldn't face any error with the answer posted  but mind posting the error as well.